# Save Current Fragment in onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have one Activity that launches a Fragment. I open my Navigation Drawer and go to a second Fragment in that same Activity. I rotate the device and instead of remaining on that second Fragment, I'm brought back to the first one. How can you save the current Fragment that you're on so that when the Activity is destroyed it opens the appropriate Fragment? Here is what I have tried but it's not working. This is in my Activity:

```
private FragmentTransaction ft;
private Fragment fragment;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);

    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {

            fragment = getFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState,"currentFrag");
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            ft.commit();
        }else{
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an
            // Intent, pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
            fragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

            // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
        }
    }
```

.....

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    getFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "currentFrag", fragment);
}
```

This is the exception in my log cat

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.FragmentTransaction android.app.FragmentTransaction.replace(int, android.app.Fragment)' on a null object reference
```

Clearly the current Fragment isn't being saved. Is this generally the correct way to solve this?

This question has nothing to do with the general understanding of what a NullPointerException is but rather how to persist Fragment states when the screen is rotated.

Comment: ? This question has nothing to do with the general understanding of what a NullPointerException is but rather how to persist Fragment states when the screen is rotated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fragment constructor, add the following line:

```
 setRetainInstance(true);
```

> Control whether a fragment instance is retained across Activity
>   re-creation (such as from a configuration change).

Comment: Im still getting the same exception. It's pretty much telling me that whatever I saved in the onSaveInstanceState method getFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "currentFrag", fragment); Isn't getting recognized when it's retrieved in the onCreate method of the Activity...fragment = getFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState,"currentFrag");

Comment: @MarkF get rid of all that code, this one line does it all

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you initialize your FragmentTransaction, sorry.
Maybe you miss this:

```
fragment = getFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState,"currentFrag");
ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
```